# How do I create a shortcut to a git host like ssh://my_shortcut/var/home/blah.git

Tags: git, ssh

On my laptop, I created a shortcut for my git host like ssh://my_shortcut/var/home/blah.git

I use it instead of the ip address to connect via ssh.

I did this a while ago and not sure how I did it, any pointers?  (I followed some tutorial that I cant' find now)

Answer (score 4):

This is precisely the purpose of [remotes](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html):

```
git remote add my-host user@host/path/to/repo.git
```

`my-host` can now be used anywhere in place of a URL, and you can use `git fetch` (or `git remote update`) to fetch all the branches in the remote into local tracking branches like `my-host/master`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the `~/.ssh/config` file. `man ssh_config` gives more information, but here is an example I'm using (anonimized):

```
Host shortcut
HostName real-computer.example.com
User username
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/svn_id_rsa
```

Now I can do `git clone ssh://shortcut/path/repo.git` instead of using the full path and username.

(If you leave the `User` directive away here, it uses the current local username, or what you give on the command line. If you leave the `IdentityFile` directive away, you'll have to use your password, or the default identity file (`id_rsa`, or such) - I created a special identity only for my svn and git connections, which does not allow remote login.)